# MonoGame Deployment

Tags: windows, monogame

I have a game in MonoGame, and I'd like to make it downloadable from my website. I'd like it if people could just download the game and then play it, though I wouldn't mind if they installed it as well. (it's a very small game, however, so I don't think they'll want to go through that process, though perhaps I'd like to offer both options!)

For now, I'd just like to deploy to Windows and make sure that works, but any advice on how to compile/deploy to Mac/Linux would be great, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually something I have always wanted to know but found little info on. From my experience which is not by any means the final answer and just something to you help down the right path...

You can follow this:[How to: Publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)

Now in my example project I was able to download it and had to install it. I know this is only one of the ways you asked but for the other way I believe you would want to make your project an executable. Which you can find a question on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126618/2444126). Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your game, you end up with a bin folder that contains a .exe file, and if you do this on mac you also get a .app file.

These are actual apps that you can play by clicking on them. This also works on other machines that don't have your development environment. You might need to include the .dll files that are in the bin folder. (I haven't tested this).

Of course, downloading an .exe is strongly discouraged since there is no way for your users to know if they are installing malware, but in theory this is possible!

[image: example]